# Javascript pair array objects order when below threshold

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object array of image properties which includes an aspect ratio. I am trying to re-order the array so that twin sets of images, equal to or below an aspect ratio of 1.1, are ordered next to each other *as pairs*.

Once a pair is next to each other in the array, the iteration continues and the order is left as is until the next image that has an aspect ratio of less than 1.1 is found. Then, again, I will find the next available image (if it exists) that has an aspect ratio of less than 1.1 and change its order so that it is next to this, creating (in terms of order) another pair.

To think of it another way: the order of all objects is to be left untouched in the array, except for any that has an aspect ratio of less than 1.1 and doesn't have a similar neighbour, creating a pair.

## Purpose

The purpose of this is that when rendering, visually, all landscape orientated images have a single line and all portrait-orientated images (which should be technically less than 1.0, yes) are paired as two together on one line.

Having the array in the order needed to do this seems like the most appropriate method.

**Current**

```
[
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.0},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 0.9},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 0.8},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.1},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
]
```

**Desired**

```
[
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.0},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 0.9},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 0.8},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.1},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
    {"url": "file.jpg", "aspect": 1.6},
]
```

I can almost think of very long winded ways of doing involving several functions but am sure I'm missing something simpler using **sort** or **filter** and `const arThreshold = 1.1`.

Most of my attempts so far involve iterating through the array and detecting that an object needs a matching pair, then finding that pair as I continue iterating. However, it gets messy when I need to mark that the 'paired' second object is not to be used when its iterated over later.

Comment: Why isn't `0.8` together with `1.0` and `0.9`? They're all below `1.1`

Comment: I mentioned pairs but this was perhaps a little unclear so I've reworded it. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @trincot I wrote it in a hurry as the format wasn't pertinent to the question, apologies if it added confusion. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` will not help with this task. Just iterate through the array, keeping track of a first occurrence. Once you have a second occurrence, perform the move, and then continue again searching for a first occurrence:

```js
let data = [
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.6},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.0},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.6},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 0.9},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.6},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 0.8},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.6},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.1},
    {'url': 'file.jpg', 'aspect': 1.6},
];

for (let i = 0, j = data.length; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].aspect < 1.1) {
        if (j <= i) {
            // rotation of the subarray j..i:
            data.splice(j, 0, ...data.splice(i, 1));
            j = data.length;
        } else {
            j = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

console.log(data);
```